# occasional reload of page in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, autopostback

I'm making a webpage in ASP.net, combined with VB.net. The current page I'm working on, is some sort of 'Quiz' webpage. The user has to fill in 40+ radiobuttons, depending on his personality and such.

Though throughout testing I've realized the webpage will occasionally reload, forcing every checked radiobutton to go back to unchecked. This will happen at seemingly random moments, sometimes not at all, sometimes 2 times in a row. This is especially annoying since there are so many radiobuttons to be checked, forcing the user to start over.

Does anybody have any idea why this could happen? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Reload doesn't happen randomly...do you have any server side event handler? Any JavaScript? Did you check network requests? If originated by a post you should be able to see who did what

Comment: Have you tried debugging and set breakpoints? Have you inserted logging to know what happens and when it happens? Also without code, it's impossible to tell what *might* be going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!Page.IsPostback)
{
  //.. your code goes here
}
```